# How to run a task in gradle with spring boot profile?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I created a task in Gradle to run a function in java, the function below

```java
tasks.register("runFunction", JavaExec) {
    main = 'com.google.cloud.functions.invoker.runner.Invoker'
    classpath(configurations.invoker)
    inputs.files(configurations.runtimeClasspath, sourceSets.main.output)
    args(
            '--target', 'gfk.stream.client.cloud.functions.excel.business.FileGenerate',
            '--port', 8081,
    )
    doFirst {
        args('--classpath', files(configurations.runtimeClasspath, sourceSets.main.output).asPath)
    }
}
```

In the spring boot application, I have configured some classes to run with `dev profile`. How do I run this task( `runFunction`) with dev profile in spring boot? btw I am using `gradlew`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Spring profile by system properties:

```gradle
tasks.register("runFunction", JavaExec) {
    systemProperty("spring.profiles.active", "dev")
    ...
}
```